# Agendar exclusão de Registro

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá, como vão vocês? Tudo bem?

---

Vou explicar minha situação e já mostrar o que eu tenho, vamos lá:

Então, eu preciso agendar a exclusão de um dado do SQL, eu tenho um sistema que publica enquetes, nessa publicação, eu defino uma DATA de exclusão, vou chamar de ***expireData***, tenho uma classe denomida ***poll***, essa classe que geri todas as informações e coletas de dados pertinente as enquetes.

Meu próximo passo é deixar isso (agendamento de exclusão) funcionando, mas tenho algumas regras para isso, não pretendo utilizar os Eventos do MySQL, quero utilizar ***PHP*** e ***CronJob***, o código que estou TENTANDO fazer é este:

```
public function sync()
{

    $sql = "DELETE FROM tb_poll WHERE active = 1 AND date < expiredate";
    $stmt = connection::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

no construtor da classe, eu chamo essa função da seguinte forma:

```
switch ($_GET['exec'])
{
    case 'dhgahjpJOPpHPhHvhKMoph':
        $this->sync();
        break;
        //restante do código
```

Então eu acesso assim: 
[?page=poll&exec=dhgahjpJOPpHPhHvhKMoph](https://meuprojeto.com.br/?page=poll&exec=dhgahjpJOPpHPhHvhKMoph)

Dito isso, o erro que obtenho do navegador é o Erro 500.

> localhost não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Já testei o DELETE apenas informando o resultado do campo active (que já é predefinido como '1'), porem, não obtive sucesso.

Obs: as tabelas são relacionadas e os campos definidos para *Default*: 0

Comment: Verifique o erro retornado no arquivo de log.

Comment: O CronJob está habilitado?

Comment: Não estou gerando nenhum log para isso, e não tenho um cronojob funcionando ainda, até porque a parte necessária para ser executada, não esta pronta.

Complementando, já descobri meu erro, como alguns campos no Banco são foreign key, eu precisei informar que o campo era ON DELETE CASCADE, se não,não funcionaria.